# What kind of question would questions that start with (and why is/should/does/would) in response to a statement, explanation, or declarative?

Tags: phrase-usage, american-english, phrase-choice

What kind of question would questions that start with (and why is/should/does/would) be in response to a statement, explanation, or declarative. What is the function of the "And" part and the function of the part after it? Are questions like these considered "follow-up" questions?

Comment: Could you edit your question with an example sentence that illustrates the type of question involved to clarify?

Comment: And why do you need an example sentence? (Would your question be a good example sentence?)

Comment: I started to take slight offense at your comment, until I realized you were actually giving me one of the examples I asked for!  My tendency to offense gives me a clue to the function of this type of structure.

Comment: This is not an English question. Most languages have "and" and can be used in this way.

Answer (score 0):

When a persons says something like: "And why did you say that?" or "And who were you with?"  They are expressing a reservation about some behavior of yours and are asking you to justify it.  I think the "and" signals that they have almost reached a negative conclusion, but want to ask the question to provide the final missing piece and give the listener one last chance to dispel their suspicion.

For example, in the question you put in your comment above.  You said: "And why do you need an example sentence?"  This seemed to express your belief that no example sentence was needed and that I should have realized that truth.  To give me one last chance to convince you that my question was worthy, you ask: "And why do you need an example sentence?"

Depending on tone, such questions can express an immediate and slightly rude challenge to the listener to justify their behavior or just a mild confusion as to why the behavior happened in the way that it did.  An example of the challenge version might add the word "just," as in: "And just why do you need an example sentence?"  An example of the milder version might be: "And why is that relevant again(, I'm not following your train of thought)?"  Again, the tone of voice would help differentiate the two usages.